# Heroku run rails db:migrate showing PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR: column "created_at" of relation "blogs" already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, activerecord

When i try to run heroku run rails db:migrate, i get the following error

```
Running rails db:migrate on ⬢ sharley... up, run.6479 (Free)
I, [2021-01-03T23:13:45.240708 #4]  INFO -- : Migrating to AddTimestampToBlogs (20201225171213)
== 20201225171213 AddTimestampToBlogs: migrating ==============================
-- add_timestamps(:blogs, {:null=>true})
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "created_at" of relation "blogs" already exists
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:47:in `exec'
/app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "created_at" of relation "blogs" already exists
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:47:in `exec'
/app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This is my schema file
Please, any help will be appreciated. Ive searched all over but to no avail.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_12_29_225613) do

  create_table "blogs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "title"
    t.string "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", precenter code hereision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_blogs_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "body"
    t.integer "blog_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "post_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["blog_id"], name: "index_comments_on_blog_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "comments", "blogs"
end
```

This is my add timestamps to blog file

```
class AddTimestampsToBlogs < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
    def change
        add_timestamps :blogs, null: true
        # backfill existing record with created_at and updated_at
        # values making clear that the records are faked
        long_ago = DateTime.new(2020, 12, 29)
        Blog.update_all(created_at: long_ago, updated_at: long_ago)
        # change not null constraints
        change_column_null :blogs, :created_at, false
        change_column_null :blogs, :updated_at, false
    end
end
```

Is there anything else needed?

Comment: To understand how you got into this situation, I would need to see any previous migration that touches the blogs table. From your schema.rb, you can see that the columns already exist. I suspect your blogs table is defined to include 'timestamps' which is shorthand for adding the created_at and updated_columns.

Comment: This is the link to my database on github.               https://github.com/Destiny-01/rails-app/tree/main/db

Comment: Your initial migration creating the blogs table includes t.timestamps. So your blog table already has created_at and updated_at and should be automatically filling in those fields as appropriate. The AddTimestampsToBlogs migration is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `add_timestamps(:blogs, {:null=>true}) unless column_exists?(:blogs, :created_at) && column_exists?(:blogs, :updated_at)`. It looks like someone deployed a migration to fix that before or something and now you're trying as well. With the conditional, it will only run the `add_timestamps` migration method if there are no created or updated at columns

**UPDATE**

In the migration add the conditional. With the conditional, it will only run that step if the timestamp columns don't exist. The issue is that you or someone on your team has run the migration on heroku before then possibly rolled back locally and then redployed. The db still has that change, hence the error you're receiving. So if you add the conditional, it will add the time stamp columns only if they already don't exist on that table

```rb
def change
        add_timestamps :blogs, null: true unless column_exists??(:blogs, :created_at) && column_exists?(:blogs, :updated_at)
        # backfill existing record with created_at and updated_at
        # values making clear that the records are faked
        long_ago = DateTime.new(2020, 12, 29)
        Blog.update_all(created_at: long_ago, updated_at: long_ago)
        # change not null constraints
        change_column_null :blogs, :created_at, false
        change_column_null :blogs, :updated_at, false
    end
```

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what to do, this is my first rails app